# Elasticsearch gives different search results for same query

Tags: elasticsearch

Problem: I get different search results for same search criteria.

I have highlighted the changes in the following screen shots:

- [1st set of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOPX.png)
- [2nd set of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0ZC0.png)

Details:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

I am using the following query to get results

```
POST facilities/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "name",
              "query": "*rad* *hom*"
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10",
  "sort": ["_score", {"name.for_sort": {"order": "asc"}}]
}
```

Comment: Try sorting by facility Id as well and see if the results vary

Comment: This can be a side-effect of sharding. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html